# After Login redirect, loginpage stays visible over new page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router to have the website redirect the user to a content page, once they input the correct password. Passed into this content page is also some props, which come from an api to display content that only logged in users can see.
When it successfully redirects, the login page is still visible over the top of the content page (see image).

[image: SignIn page contents displaying over content page]

Sign In code:

```
export const SignIn = (props) => {
const[text, setText] = useState();
const[signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState(false);
const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;

async function sendPassword(password){
    const res = fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/paid",{
        method: "POST",
        mode: "cors",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({password})
    })
    return res
}

async function submit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const res = await sendPassword(text)
    if (await res.status == 200){
        const json = await res.json()
        props.setter(json)
        setSignedIn(<Redirect to="/training"/>);            
    }else{
        document.getElementById("incorrect").style.display="flex"
    }
}

return (
    <SignInContainer>
        {signedIn == false ?
            <SignInWrapper>
                <SignInHeader>Sign In</SignInHeader>
                <Image src={logo}/>
                <InputWrapper onSubmit={submit}>
                    <InputBox onChange={(e)=> {setText(e.target.value)}} placeholder="Instert PassKey"/>
                    <Button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</Button> {/*clear the textbox*/}
                    <RejectionText id="incorrect">Incorrect Password</RejectionText>
                </InputWrapper>
            </SignInWrapper>
        
        : signedIn}
    </SignInContainer>
)
```

}

NavBar Code (Where SignIn is called from)

```
const NavBar = ({toggle}) => {
return (
    <>
        <Nav>
            <NavLink to="/" style={{width:"30%"}}>
                <Image src={Logo}/>
            </NavLink>
            <NavMenu>
                <NavLink to="/about" activeStyle>About Us</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/training" activeStyle>Training Resources</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/contact" activeStyle>Contact Us</NavLink>
            </NavMenu>
            <NavBtn>
                <NavBtnLink to="/signin" activeStyle>Sign In</NavBtnLink>
            </NavBtn>
        </Nav>
    </>
)
```

}

TrainingPage (where SignIn redirects to)

```
export const Training = (props) => {
const[freeCourses, setFreeCourses] = useState([])
const[SelectedContent, setSelectedContent] = useState("https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=BF3138943720AE9B&resid=BF3138943720AE9B%2114069&authkey=AKEyx39blf01VCI&em=2")

useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/free")
        .then((res) => {
            return res.json()
        }).then((json) => {
            setFreeCourses(json)
        })
},[])


function ContentSelection(url){
    console.log(url)
    setSelectedContent(url)
    console.log(SelectedContent)
}

return (
    <TrainingContainer>
        <ContentWrapper>
            <ContentHeader>{}</ContentHeader>
            <ContentFrame src={SelectedContent}>Your Browser Does not support this content</ContentFrame>
        </ContentWrapper>
        <SelectorWrapper>
            <FreeContentContainer>
                <FreeContentHeader>Your Free Content</FreeContentHeader>
                <FreeContentWrapper>                        
                    {freeCourses.map(course => {
                        return (<Content href={course.url} key={course.id} onClick={() => ContentSelection(course.url)}><ContentImg src={`http://localhost:5000/api/images/${course.imgID}`} alt="Not working"/></Content>) //Redesign this
                    })}
                </FreeContentWrapper>
            </FreeContentContainer>
            <PaidContentContainer>
                <PaidContentHeader>Your Paid Content</PaidContentHeader>
                <PaidContentWrapper>
                    {props.courses.map(course => {
                        console.log(course)
                        return (<Content href={course.url} key={course.id}>{course.title}</Content>) //Redesign this
                    })}
                </PaidContentWrapper>
            </PaidContentContainer>
        </SelectorWrapper>
    </TrainingContainer>
)
```

}

Comment: I think you are missing brackets for first part of **ternary operator**

Comment: Thanks for the response Akhil.
Do you mind elaborating your point?
It's a shame SO doesn't show the line numbers, as I'm confused about which the line of code you're referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you have *should* work but it's anti-pattern in React to store JSX into component state. You can easily conditionally render the login UI or the redirect from the `signedIn` state.

```
export const SignIn = (props) => {
  const[text, setText] = useState();
  const[signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState(false);
  const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;

  async function sendPassword(password){
    ...
  }

  async function submit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const res = await sendPassword(text)
    if (await res.status == 200){
      const json = await res.json()
      props.setter(json)
      setSignedIn(true); // <-- toggle true
    } else {
      document.getElementById("incorrect").style.display="flex"
    }
  }

  // conditionally render Redirect if logged in
  if (signedIn) return <Redirect to="/training" />;

  return (
    <SignInContainer>
      <SignInWrapper>
        <SignInHeader>Sign In</SignInHeader>
        <Image src={logo}/>
        <InputWrapper onSubmit={submit}>
          <InputBox onChange={(e)=> {setText(e.target.value)}} placeholder="Instert PassKey"/>
          <Button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</Button> {/*clear the textbox*/}
          <RejectionText id="incorrect">Incorrect Password</RejectionText>
        </InputWrapper>
      </SignInWrapper>
    </SignInContainer>
  )
}
```

I suspect you are still matching and rendering this `SignIn` component in your `Router` and/or `Switch`, so double check that you are correctly ordering your paths so path specificity works. Please add how you are rendering this `SignIn` component and other routes so we can confirm.

Additionally, you should probably store this authentication state in a component that is mounted a bit longer, like the root `App` component, or in redux state, or localStorage, etc... it's your choice how to persist authentication in your UI.

Comment: Thanks for the response Drew.

Unfortunately this hasn't fixed the issue and the elements are still visible after the redirect.

Comment: @JamesRatcliffe Right, that means something is still rendering this component *after* being redirected, can you include *that* code in your question?

Comment: The SignIn page is only called when the button on the navbar is clicked. The training page which it redirects to is a fairly simple html page which just renders components using called json data. 
The props data passed through from the signin is used to fill the paid content list, visible in the image.
I can still upload the code if you would like, but would that be the NavBar (where its called from), or the TrainingPage (where it goes to)?

Comment: @JamesRatcliffe Yes, please. It would be helpful to see all the code from routing through to this `SignIn` component.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the NavBar and Training page code.
I greatly appreciate your help as I've been stumped with this.

Comment: @JamesRatcliffe What is rendering `SignIn`? The path from router to `SignIn` is likely where the issue lies.

Comment: the Router is initialised in the App.js I tried to add the code snippet but it keeps bugging out in SO. It's essentially this:

<Route path="/signin" exact><SigninPage setter={setCourses}/></Route>

Comment: When I first made the signin page as a quick test, it would remove the content. But only when the only thing that it's rendering was 2 inputs inside the form. Since adding more content and updating them to stylised components, this issue has occured.

Comment: Hey Drew. Just a quick update. I managed to fix it. You were spot on. I was accidentally calling the SignIn page when I didn't need to be from the training page. So obvious now that I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to use React Router and the Context API to store information about the user. If the user is null, redirect all links to the login page, else redirect the login page to the home page.

I also noticed that you are accessing the `RejectionText` component directly using `getElementById`. This isn't recommended in React, and you can use a flag variable as a state variable to check if there's an error or not.

Comment: Thanks for the response Nikhil.
I noticed that there are certain ways to have the element become visible in react, although it's all new to me. I'll look into it. Thanks for the help.